# Are the Sleepgivers mentioned in the (chronologically) later Valdemar books?

Tags: mercedes-lackey, valdemar

I'm currently reading *Spy, Spy Again*, third book in the most recent Mercedes Lackey Valdemar series, *Family Spies*, following the progeny of Mags, an orphan Herald of Valdemar and early graduate of what has become the Collegium in the later books (so set after the Vanyel books, but before most of the others). One of the plot points in the earlier Collegium books is that Mags finally meets his family, a mysterious sect of desert assassins, and in this book, they're put to the forefront of the plot with us getting insights into their culture. In the midst of my musings that, much as usual for Misty's work, the Sleepgivers are better than everyone else at just about anything, being deadly assassins for hire with a socialist sharing of resources, trained in magic, able to clam their minds so much that they can't be detected by mind magic, possessing horses that rival those of the Shin'a'in, etc, and that it's odd that there's no mention of them in the later books, having been invented for his prequel.

But then it struck me... are they actually absent in those books? I mean, it's possible they just never quite came up, or there's a plot point that will result in them being eliminated, or at least greatly reduced, but maybe they were part of the world all along and I just didn't remember mentions of them. So, have they shown up in books other than the *Collegium Chronicles* and the *Family Spies* series?

Comment: Unless they are in that Owl trilogy which I didn't read I don't remember them.

Comment: The Family Spies books are the latest to be written, so Misty hadn't invented the Sleepgivers when she wrote the earlier books.

Comment: I was considering the possibility that she had invented them before as part of her world building, but just not elaborated on them.